# Good practice to implement a ThreadPool of intensive processing inside a Django App

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm working with [Django using Daphne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/daphne/) (so, It's an async app). In my site users can run expensive experiments. I'd like the users not to wait, so I decided to implement a "global" ThreadPool running in background. These are the steps I followed:

1. I made a Singleton service:

```py
class TaskQueue(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.instance is not None:
            return cls.instance
        else:
            # Creates the instance
            cls.instance = super(TaskQueue, cls).__new__(cls)

            cls.instance.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=settings.THREAD_POOL_SIZE)

            # Gets the pending experiments
            cls.instance.get_not_computed_experiments()
            return cls.instance

    def eval_mrna_gem_experiment(self, experiment: Experiment) -> None:
        # Some long code...

    def add_experiment(self, experiment: Experiment):
        self.executor.submit(self.eval_mrna_gem_experiment, experiment)


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_queue():
    """
    Caches the TaskQueue instantiation
    """
    return TaskQueue()
```

2. Every time a user makes a request to execute an experiment I do:

```py
get_queue().add_experiment(new_experiment)
```

I think this way there's a global queue which computes the experiments in order. The questions are:

- Is there a correct way to implement that? **Keep in mind** that in `eval_mrna_gem_experiment` I make several call to R apis in the SO using [rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html), so I don't know if It's a bad practice as there is a Main Thread (the app) deploying a ThreadPool which calls R code which has several threads running to compute expensive stuff.
- Does Singleton pattern apply to this kind of problem? Or there is a better alternative? For example, I found [this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/70073915986/) where he just use an instance and import it in `views.py`, but I would like to use it in several files

Any kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance